# Bug menu Side-bar PHP Yii 1.1 using Template

Tags: php, jquery, css, yii-extensions, yii1.x

i try apply theme gentelella with my project using framework yii 1.1. Here i use extension Yii 1.1 that is CMenu, when I want to match the original code template i have a problem with my project in side-bar ( [my menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idb21.png) ), which should ([template menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WS8x.png))

for my code:
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeIdb.png)

```
!-- sidebar menu -->
<div id="sidebar-menu", class="main_menu_side hidden-print main_menu">
<div class="menu_section">
          <?php
          if(!Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
          {
            $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array(
            'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'nav side-menu'),
            'submenuHtmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'nav child_menu'),
            'encodeLabel'=>false,
            'items'=>Yii::app()->user->getState('menu'),
            ));
          }
          else
            echo '<div id=\'footer\'></div>';
        ?>
</div>
</div>
<!-- /sidebar menu -->
```

for the template code: [code template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvh7I.png)

```
<!-- sidebar menu -->
        <div id="sidebar-menu" class="main_menu_side hidden-print main_menu">
          <div class="menu_section">
            <h3>General</h3>
            <ul class="nav side-menu">
              <li><a><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                <ul class="nav child_menu">
                  <li><a href="index.html">Dashboard</a></li>
                  <li><a href="index2.html">Dashboard2</a></li>
                  <li><a href="index3.html">Dashboard3</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              </ul>
          </div>
          <!-- <div class="menu_section"> -->
            <ul class="nav side-menu">
              <li><a><i class="fa fa-bug"></i> Additional Pages <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                <ul class="nav child_menu">
                  <li><a href="e_commerce.html">E-commerce</a></li>
                  <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
                  <li><a href="project_detail.html">Project Detail</a></li>
                  <li><a href="contacts.html">Contacts</a></li>
                  <li><a href="profile.html">Profile</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /sidebar menu -->
```

i have try to insert `<ul class="nav child_menu">` under `<div class="menu_section">` but what happens is that the menu does not appear :(

please help, 
thanks